# Map with Janestreet Core_kernel

Tags: ocaml

I'm doing Real World Ocaml, with Ocaml 4.06, emacs/merlin.
Please see following code snippet. I have two questions:

```
open Core_kernel

let () =
  let digit_alist = [ 0, "zero"; 1, "one"; 2, "two"  ; 3, "three"; 4, "four";
                      5, "five"; 6, "six"; 7, "seven"; 8, "eight"; 9, "nine" ] in
  let _ = Map.of_alist_exn digit_alist ~comparator:Int.comparator in
  ()
```

When evaluating from merlin, it shows two errors. It looks like that `Map.of_alist_exn` does not accept labeled argument `~comparator`.:

```
This expression has type (int * string) list
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a, 'b) Core_kernel.Map.comparator =
           (module Core_kernel__.Comparator.S with type comparator_witness = 'b and type t = 'a)

The function applied to this argument has type
         ('a * 'b) Core_kernel__.Import.list -> ('a, 'b, 'c) Base__Map.t
This argument cannot be applied with label ~comparator
```

Q1) Has the function type of `Map.of_alist_exn` changed?

And I think that the function type has been changed. So I changed the source code like this:

```
open Core_kernel

let () =
  let digit_alist = [ 0, "zero"; 1, "one"; 2, "two"  ; 3, "three"; 4, "four";
                      5, "five"; 6, "six"; 7, "seven"; 8, "eight"; 9, "nine" ] in
  let _ = Map.of_alist_exn Int.comparator digit_alist in
  ()
```

At this time, merlin complains like this:

```
This expression has type
         (Core_kernel.Int.t, Core_kernel.Int.comparator_witness)
         Core_kernel__.Comparator.comparator =
           (Core_kernel.Int.t, Core_kernel.Int.comparator_witness)
           Base__Comparator.t
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a, 'b) Core_kernel.Map.comparator =
           (module Core_kernel__.Comparator.S with type comparator_witness = 'b and type t = 'a)
```

I expect `Int.comparator` will do the role of valid comparator, but ocaml regard it as invalid.

Q2) What should I give it for comparator?

@A struggling noob

Comment: for Q2) `Map.of_alist_exn (module Int) digit_alist` ? Doesn't dev version of Real World Ocaml serve for introduction to Janestreet core library?

Comment: I cannot understand why `(module Int)` can be a valid argument for `Map.of_alist_exn` which has a type of `('a, 'cmp) Core_kernel.Map.comparator -> ('a * 'b) Core_kernel__.Import.list -> ('a, 'b, 'cmp) Core_kernel.Map.t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the definition of `comparator`, we can see it defined as following,

```
type ('k, 'cmp) comparator = (module Comparator.S with type comparator_witness = 'cmp and type t = 'k)
```

In ocaml, modules can be used as first class values. One interesting consequence of that feature is that modules can now be defined as types and be passed/used as function parameters/arguments. Janestreet `core_kernel` and/or `base` makes heavy use of first class modules as you have found out. `Map.comparator` is one such use case.

`Comparator.S` is defined as follows:

```
module type Core_kernel.Comparator.S
type t
type comparator_witness
val comparator : (t, comparator_witness) comparator
```

If you look at the module signature for `module Int` - `#show Core_kernel.Int` in `utop`, then we can see that it defines the type and the functions as prescribed in `Core_kernel.Comparator.S` module type.

Thus, `Map.of_alist_exn` accepts `(module Int)` as a valid parameter. `(module Int)` is the ocaml syntax which denotes that the value is being passed as a first class module.

Refs:

1. https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core_kernel/Core_kernel/Map/#type-comparator
2. https://ocaml.janestreet.com/ocaml-core/latest/doc/core_kernel/Core_kernel/Comparator/module-type-S/